# Sending a DELETE request with EJS using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have already made a Restful API with node and everything works but I am trying to add EJS to it so I can use HTML&CSS, I implemented GET and POST just fine but I am tripping up on DELETE.

Here is my code in my router to delete

```
listRouter.delete('/:id', 
    function(req, res) {
        req.list = list;
        req.list.remove(function(err){
            if (err)
                res.status(500).send(err);
            else
                res.redirect('/')
        });
});
```

and here's my EJS for deletion

```
<form method="DELETE" action="/:id">
      <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

and this is the error I receive when I press the button

```
{
message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id"",
name: "CastError",
kind: "ObjectId",
value: ":id",
path: "_id"
}
```

The thing is though the same exact code works if it's modified for JSON so I don't know if its EJS or my Javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

i think html5 just support `post` and `get` in method form attribute

however, in my case if i don't using form for submit, here example

> example in html or front end

```
<a class="btn btn-raised btn-danger" href="/admin/dashboard/detele/<%= data.userId %>">Delete</a></td> 
<!-- The href needs to point at a link where data.userId is shown. Hence you need the = after <% for ejs to show the variable. -->
```

> In app.js for the url delete

```
app.get('/admin/dashboard/detele/:id', users.deleteUser);
```

> in express users.js

```
exports.deleteUser = function(req, res) {

    users.findOneAndRemove({
        userId: req.params.id
    }, function(err, user) {

        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("Success");

    });

    res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');

}
```

> don't forget creating mongo model for mongoose

```
var skema = new mongo.Schema({

    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    admin: Boolean
});


var users = mongo.model('accounts', skema);
```

i using EJS here, hope it's help you

- [more helpful link1](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications)
- [more helpful link2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4)

Comment: Just a small change, how use deleteOne(...), findOneAndRemove(...) is deprecated.

Comment: Don't use anchor tags for initiating requests. Anchor tags will always be clicked on by bots and crawlers and you don't want the bots to delete stuff from your site.

Answer (score 1):

giving up use of *method-override* can be solution

I used different url to solve this.

```
<form action="/quake/forum/update/<%= post._id %>?_method=put" method="post">
```

and

```
<form action="/quake/forum/delete/<%= post._id %>?_method=delete" method="post" class="d-inline">
```

and router

main router

```
app.use('/quake/forum',forumRouter); //this is for just making sure explaination clear
```

sub router (forumRouter)

```
router.post('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
```

and

```
router.post('/update/:id', function (req, res) {
```